# How to implicitly add the N in the prefix for NVARCHAR

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an ASP.net page. There I can enter the Non-English language character into an input control (like a textbox). I want to store it in my SQL Server 2000 database as same language characters.

I pass the value as string to the `nvarchar` variable in my stored procedure.

My problem is, if you want to store the value in `nvarchar` character, you have to add `N` as prefix. How do I add this `N` in the prefix of `sp_variable`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `N` prefix only to indicate that a hard-coded string value is `nvarchar` in SQL queries. C# `string` maps to both `varchar` and `nvarchar` of SQL Server.

To let SQL know you are passing `unicode` string, you should be doing this:

```
var cmd  = new SqlCommand("your_sp_name", sqlConn);
var sp_param = new SqlParameter("@sp_variable", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
sp_param.Value = "unicode_chars_string_value";
cmd.Parameters.Add(sp_param);
```

Comment: Thanks dude. You saved me.